# Reset link counters

Tags: network-interface, iproute

Preferably **without bringing down the interface** I'd like to reset interface link counters; bonus points if it can be done with `iproute2` tools.

Comment: Well have you tried anything?

Comment: According to the Google in multiple places this is the only current way to do it

Comment: Well let me know if you find a way then

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/348038/how-to-reset-ifconfig-counters?newreg=321e2029f9444fe297c71de2d972a40b

Answer (score 1):

This **cant be done with `iproute2` neither without unloading the kernel module**. If the module is kernel built-in . The common solutions are unloading the module as a lot of internet knowledge says:

- [How do I clear the interface stats on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/23687/how-do-i-clear-the-interface-stats-on-linux)
- [Resetting Ifconfig Counters](http://www.ducea.com/2006/09/08/resetting-ifconfig-counters/)
- Ubuntu Forum: Thread: [Resetting ifconfig counters](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2065071)
- [How to reset ifconfig counters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348038/how-to-reset-ifconfig-counters) - Ask Ubuntu

[iproute2](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.1.1) does not have a "flush counters" function. You could take a look at `/sys/class/net/<iface>/statistics/rx_packets` and other files inside this directory, but they are all read-only.

A possible solution should be use the [crash](http://wiki.adrienmahieux.fr/computing/system/linux/crash/reset_network_errors) command, however a kernel compiled with debug options will be required.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick overview you can show the statistics of an interface with, for example:

```
rpi ~$ ip -stats -stats link show wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:7f:38:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    25097241   281838   0       0       0       0
    RX errors: length   crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    34492878   281896   0       0       0       0
    TX errors: aborted  fifo   window heartbeat transns
               0        0       0       0       2
```

More details you can find at:

```
rpi ~$ ls /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/
collisions     rx_crc_errors   rx_frame_errors   rx_over_errors     tx_carrier_errors  tx_fifo_errors
multicast      rx_dropped      rx_length_errors  rx_packets         tx_compressed      tx_heartbeat_errors
rx_bytes       rx_errors       rx_missed_errors  tx_aborted_errors  tx_dropped         tx_packets
rx_compressed  rx_fifo_errors  rx_nohandler      tx_bytes           tx_errors          tx_window_errors

rpi ~$ cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/tx_packets 
300409
```

The only issue is that you cannot reset these counters without unloading the networking driver. They are all read-only. But with some little bash scripting this shouldn't be a problem.